# How do I wait for flash (as2) to load child elements before running some code?

Tags: flash, null, movieclip, actionscript-2

On the stage, I have seven buttons. I want to add events on these buttons, however most of them are "undefined"/null. How do I wait for the stage or _root in as2 to finish loading the child elements before doing anything.

Is there an equivalent to flex 3 applicationComplete?
`<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" applicationComplete="init()">`

Comment: It turns out that I had a duplicate instance name. After fixing that and moving the buttons to a different layer and frame, it started working. I can't recreate the problem, even after putting the elements back to the way they were.

Comment: I'm still curious how to accomplish this though.

Comment: Unless you are loading them dynamically, the scripts on the timeline will not fire until the whole frame is loaded. If you were using some class code, anything could have happened, depending on what the code in your class is doing. So basically, you threw random instance names and they failed because of that. this "applicationComplete" can be aproximated with _root.getBytesLoaded() and _root.getBytesTotal()...

Comment: Also, you're going to have to write a much better question to get a meaningful answer. The reason you did not get any answers within 5 minutes is because the question is anything but a question :)

Comment: You answered my question perfectly. I'll have to work harder to come up with more concise questions while adequately describing the situation, without confusing the reader. Can you post the voted comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that your movieclip is created with all children you should use onLoaded handler.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-7868.html

It is strange that you experience such problem if you place you code in fla frame.